# Fire rated EN 13501-1 B-s1/s2, d0 sheets

Tags: heat-transfer, metals, plastic, material-science, metal-folding

I'm trying to learn more about the type of sheets I can get for a project, I would of course go for polycarbonate if not for its price, currently the project with PC will cost \$600-\$700
but I'm hoping for something cheaper.

- It does **not** need to be transparent, will go for solid black (doors will be PC)
- It does **not** need to be highly scratch resistant / impact resistant
- It needs to **Withstand** high temp (130 °C~)
- Fire retardant, or at most won't contribute to a fire

It' going be a used as a few things (don't judge :) )
Mainly homemade vacuumed curing station with medium heat (30 °C - 70 °C)

Materials I already thought about but found them to be either expensive or not fire safe enough (correct me if i'm wrong)

- PC
- Metal sheets - expensive
- ACM - expensive (mineral version for fire rating)
- ABS - Won't withstand fire
- PVC - Won't withstand fire
- Glass (This one actually tick all the boxes but it's so hard to handle)

It checked for 4mm sheets, 2050 mm X 1250 mm

Recommendation for other materials to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Reaction to fire tests Calcium Silicate boards or gypsum boards are often used as substrate; these boards are classified as A1 or A2 according to the european EN 13501-1 standard.
These boards are

- not transparent, most often white,
- are not really scratch resistant
- can withstand a really high temperature (200°C, 300°C, some CaSi boards can withstand a temperatures as high as 1100°C which is obv overkill here)
- as they are classified A or A2 according to the EN 13501-1 they don't contribute to a fire.

You can find them in all size and prices.
You can also look into cement boards.

In the long term the CaSi boards can be sensitive to high changes in temperature (think of a fire against the plate, then cold water against the plate)